# Привидение к неполному типу void

Tags: c++

Какую полезную работу может делать такое привидение

```
(void)переменная
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так обычно пишут чтобы компилятор не ругался на неиспользуемую переменную. И ещё вроде чтобы компилятор при оптимизации не удалял эту переменную.

Comment: Обычно 
1) просто комментируют объявление
2) гасят пердуперждение указанием соответсвующего ключа.

Comment: @BwanaTheMaster В Qt есть макрос `Q_UNUSED`:`Indicates to the compiler that the parameter with the specified name is not used in the body of a function. This can be used to suppress compiler warnings while allowing functions to be defined with meaningful parameter names in their signatures.` В `qglobal.h`: `#  define Q_UNUSED(x) (void)x;` [Вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19576884/3503216) в котором есть пример зачем такое может понадобиться. А ключ компиляции погасит все предупреждения (насчёт этого не уверен, поправьте меня если я не прав)